# How to make use of "Time stamp" column in Multiple Linear regression using Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe where i need to predict the CPU usage based on other columns. This is a multiple regression problem.

The dataframe looks like this

```
Time         CPU utilization time         Process memory    CPU usage       process name
10:32:44         18:30:54                   0.05              6.3              rcu_bhi
11:43:21         21:56:22                   1.09              5.4              bhi_nnd
```

I want to predict "CPU usage" column based on other predictors. I would like to know how to use "Time" and "CPU utilization time" columns as independent features?. both the columns are in "hh:mm:ss" format and these two columns are important for my predictions.

How to make use of these columns as my independent variables? What steps should I follow.

Comment: Do you also have the date? What happens when the time goes past midnight? How will get the order right? This will be critical when figuring out your train-test splits in order to not leak information from the future

Comment: I have actually removed the date from "Time" column. But the "CPU utilization time" column has only the time stamp as how many hours that particular cpu has utilized

Comment: Yeah so `Time` is a datetime whereas utilization_time is a timedelta. Don't drop the date frmo your `Time` column. So basic ways to use these data are to convert the datetime [into date-parts](https://docs.fast.ai/tabular.transform.html#Treating-date-columns) or make a float that is the time in seconds since a reference time. Convert the time delta into a float like time in seconds. Also take a look at the [darts](https://github.com/unit8co/darts) package for more advanced approaches.

Comment: also be very careful when splitting your data. Take a look at sklearn's [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) functionality.

Comment: Another approach is to calculate stats over time windows e.g. mean / stddev / max  CPU usage over the past 1, 5, and 24 hours etc

Comment: ok. Let me check. thanks for your suggestion